# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded_of'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am getting attribute error while installing the dependencies via pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 210, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 319, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 344, in resolve
    success = self._backtrack()
  File "/home/jpg/.virtual_env/cloud/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 287, in _backtrack
    criterion = self.state.criteria[name].excluded_of([candidate])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded_of'
```

My `requirements.txt` looks like as

```
celery==5.0.2
billiard<4.0,>=3.6.0
redis==3.5.3
redis-log-handler==0.0.1.dev32
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9180

Comment: I hope I  already  have pinned the [reference below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65085052/12578202)

Answer (score 8):

### Update - 1 (on 2020-12-27)

The issue has been fixed in **`pip==20.3.3`** and thus you will not receive this exception.

But, (here) the `redis-log-handler==0.0.1.dev32` depends on `redis==3.0.1` but, you have `redis==3.5.3` on the requirements.txt and hence the *dependencies **will not resolve***. So, you will further receive and an error (I would say, a *validation error*) as,

> ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 4) and redis==3.5.3
> because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
>
> The conflict is caused by:
> The user requested redis==3.5.3
> redis-log-handler 0.0.1.dev32 depends on redis==3.0.1
>
> To fix this you could try to:
>
> 1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
> 2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

This error report is pretty much helpful and it is time to adjust your package dependencies.

**Note:** *If you are not interested in adjusting the dependencies and want to resolve it as before, go though the below section*

---

### Original Post

This is an issue with [pip version `20.3`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9180) and <strike>not yet fixed</strike> fixed in **`pip==20.3.3`**.

#### Method 1

Install the previous stable version of the pip (20.2.X) by,

```
pip install --upgrade pip~=20.2.0
```

#### Method 2

Use **`--use-deprecated`** flag while ***installing the requirements***

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Comment: tried this, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You will not get the same error unless you are using `pip==20.3` . You can verify the pip version that you are using by ***`pip -V`*** command @AbhinavRalhan