# How to install incompatible packages with pip version v20.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip, virtualenv

Since PIP has released v20.3, I am not able to install my requirements without upgrading my Django version to match versions of other packages. This was just a warning up until this version but now the installation itself is blocked. Since upgrading Django and other packages for the entire project may take a week, am looking for a temporary solution that will allow to me to continue installation with the current Django version.

I have tried installing with an older version of PIP but that is also failing now. I tried downgrading the packages which was throwing an incompatible higher version but the installation is stuck while pip is searching for suitable versions to be installed.

NOTE: Am focussing only on fixing incompatible versions issue which could have other solutions apart from downgrading pip hence this question is different from the other similar questions suggested which also has issues that can be fixed by downgrading pip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded\_of'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085051/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-excluded-of)

Comment: the issue is with pip 20.3, use `pip V20.2.X`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Worked with v20.2.4