# Installing JupyterLab using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install JupyterLab on my windows system using **pip install jupyterlab**, but I am getting an error as shown below:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 224, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 320, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 344, in resolve
    success = self._backtrack()
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 287, in _backtrack
    criterion = self.state.criteria[name].excluded_of([candidate])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded_of'
```

what might be the reason?

Comment: Is that all the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'excluded\_of'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085051/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-excluded-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [latest Python release at the time of writing is 3.9.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/), but it looks like you are trying to use Python 3.10:

```
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\
```

This must be a pre-release of some sort. I suggest you try using a stable release instead.

Answer (score 1):

To download open terminal and type:

> > > pip install jupyterlab

To open type:

> > > jupyter-lab

Comment: OP already tried `pip install jupyterlab` and received an error, as shown in the question.

Comment: i've been trying `jupyterlab` to launch it, but it should be `jupyter-lab`, so thanks for the inspiration!!